# "Circular" hiking trails in Iceland?

Tags: hiking, iceland

In September I will be travelling to Iceland, and renting a car there to make a trip around most of the country. One of the main activities will be hiking, and I am looking to do one hiking trip that takes around 4 days to complete (walking around 15-20 km per day). I have been looking up quite some trails, but all of them seem to go from point A to point B, whereas I would like to return at point A, so that I'll end up where I left my car. I am absolutely not keen on relying on public transport or hitch-hiking to get back where my car is.

Do you know of any hiking trails that are suitable for this? So far I am having no luck.

Comment: I was able to find a few loop trails here: http://www.wikiloc.com/trails/hiking/iceland?t=1&

Comment: Just buy some Atlaskort and navigate on your own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that most documented Icelandic hikes are one way because of the ring road - you'll end up somewhere else on the main road after four days walk.

[This hiking map](http://www.international-photographer.com/maps/iceland/) looks like it would give some roll-your-own circular routes if you're interested in the well-pathed areas like the south.

Your best bet will probably be to contact the [Icelandic Touring Association](http://www.fi.is/en/about-ita/) (who maintain their own [hiking list](http://www.fi.is/en/hiking-trails/)) or [Nordic Adventure Travel](http://www.nat.is/company_info.htm) (who maintain [similar maps of hikes](http://www.nat.is/gonguleidireng/gonguleidir_allt_landid.htm)).